# Interpreting variable names in radare2

Tags: radare2

I am reversing an ELF executable, and got the following:

```
0x080480ab      b880800408     movl $entry0, %eax          ; eip
0x080480b0      bb23810408     movl $section_end.LOAD0, %ebx ; section_end.LOAD0
```

It turned out that `entry0` contains the beginning of the `.text` section and `section_end.LOAD0` the end of it. However, this was not clear for immediately (`entry0` is now clear, but I still do not know the origin of name `section_end.LOAD0`). Is there a documentation for these names? If not, can I ask `radare2` to use memory addresses instead of these names?

Comment: Typically, those are explicitly exported symbols, and your disassembler helpfully replaces the addresses with the exported name.

Comment: How can I improve the question dear downvoter?

Answer (score 2):

`entry0` is the first entrypoint of your binary, `section_end.LOAD0` is likely the end of the first (hence the `0`) LOADable section :)